# Wildcards in a Query String C#

Tags: c#, winforms, api, query-string

Not sure how to ask this or if it can be done.

I have an ID number, that I want to test if it matches an ID in a URL query string that is stored in an API I am working with.

So if the URL i want to search contains a `http://www.testurl.com/page?key=55555`, I just want to put in my http request if that url 'contains' that number. Testing if the url is exactly equal has proved problematic as there is a lot of other info the stored query string.

Are wildcards within query strings even possible, considering I am encoding the html already? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] myUrls = new string[] {
  "http://www.testurl.com/page?key=55555",
  "http://www.testurl.com/page?key=555556789",
  "http://www.testurl.com/page?foo=bar&key=55555&baz=938355555"};

string myToken = "key=55555";
bool exists;

foreach(string url in myUrls)
{
    System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(url);
    string q = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Query, UriFormat.Unescaped);

    if (q.Split('&').Any(x=>x== myToken))
    {
       Console.WriteLine(string.Format("found it in '{0}'", url));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can access the QueryString, you could just do this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["key"].ToLower() == "5555")
    //do something
```